# Aggregate WITHOUT Group By returning duplicates

Tags: sql-server, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have the following data.

```
Property, Value
Odd,1
Even,2
Odd,3
Even,4
Odd,5
Even,6
```

With GROUP BY

```
SELECT Property, COUNT(*) FROM Tab1 GROUP BY Property
```

Result:

```
Property, COUNT(*)
Odd 3
Even 3
```

But when I am using the aggregate function it is returning duplicate values.

```
SELECT property,count(*) over (partition by property) AS count
FROM Tab1;
```

Result

```
Property, count
Even 3
Even 3
Even 3
Odd 3
Odd 3
Odd 3
```

I want the same result as I get using GROUP BY.

---

```
SELECT property, count FROM (
SELECT property,count(*) over (partition by property) AS count
FROM Tab1) AS tab2;
```

Is there any other method than this?

Answer (score 1):

That's how window functions work; you get a row returned for every row in the source table, not an aggregated row as when you use `GROUP BY`. You can achieve the same result using `SELECT DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT property,
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY property) AS count
FROM Tab1
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0ee28b86d6c93ceab63ce687836172fd)